# innerHTML breaking setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval, innerhtml

Does anyone know why this happens? Placing an image and then setting a setInterval function to animate it. Then adding HTML to the parent div breaks the animation.

```
document.getElementById('whiteboard').innerHTML = '<img id="mule" src="http://childscript.com/art/mule.png" />';  //image with id mule

csE = document.getElementById('mule');
setInterval(function(){ csE.style.transform = 'rotate(' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 -45) + 'deg)'; }, 100);

// following line breaks the code???
document.getElementById('whiteboard').innerHTML += 'hey';
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gt6w3dhb/

Answer (score 0):

Because when you are replacing the innerHTML, it is replacing the existing dom elements.

In your case the `csE` variable refers to a dom element which does not exists in the dom after you replaces the `innerHTML`

So the solution is to append the new elements to the dom, instead of using string concatenation of `innerHTML`

```js
document.getElementById('whiteboard').innerHTML = '<img id="mule" src="http://childscript.com/art/mule.png" />';

csE = document.getElementById('mule');
setInterval(function() {
  csE.style.transform = 'rotate(' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 - 45) + 'deg)';
}, 100);

var txt = document.createTextNod('hey');
document.getElementById('whiteboard').appendChild(txt)
```

```html
<div id="whiteboard"></div>
```